# (GCP/GCE) Update gcloud SDK to use VPN tools

Tags: vpn, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've been using GCE and gcloud for a few weeks now. A new set of VPN tools were released in alpha last Dec. 3rd (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn), and I need to start testing with them.

The problem is that gcloud doesn't seem to recognise this new set of tools, and I get errors like:

```
$ gcloud compute target-vpn-gateways create --region us-central1 --network default vpn1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute) Invalid choice: 'target-vpn-gateways'.
$ gcloud compute vpn-tunnels describe
ERROR: (gcloud.compute) Invalid choice: 'vpn-tunnels'
```

*target-vpn-gateways* and *vpn-tunnels* are just not part of the command groups.

So, I though of updating the core and compute components, but they're all up to date. This seems so new that there's no information at this time in Google Cloud documentation about updating the SDK to be able to use these VPN tools.

Any ideas?  I'm using OSX in case it matters.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**

As of March 2015, the documentation has been updated and it's now in beta stage:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn

So, to answer my own question according to this update, beta VPN functionality can be accessed by updating components this way:

```
$ gcloud components update beta
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the confusion here.  Google Cloud Platform support is still in limited preview state.  What this means is that the API calls only work for specially whitelisted projects and that the normal gcloud build doesn't yet include VPN support.  (Because it would be potentially confusing if the gcloud command existed but would always fail do the API not being enabled yet.)

As I understand it your best bet for getting your project whitelisted is to go through the GCP sales office:
  https://cloud.google.com/contact/

I'm going to try to get the docs updated so that the situation is more clear.

Comment: I also read in [launch stages](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages) that "Alpha customers need to apply for access", I'll try to contact Sales as suggested. I'll update the post when they get back at me. Thank you!

Comment: I contacted Sales and they called me back, but they didn't seem to understand what I was talking about regarding Alpha releases and requesting for access. Thanks anyway  :-)

Comment: Hello! At the end, Sales didn't contact me again. Since you seem to be working there, would you please have an idea of how long would it take to get this VPN tools to Beta? Of course I understand it would be a very rough estimate, I just need to know whether it usually takes a few weeks or a few months to move forward to the next phase. Would you know? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was announced in GCP Live that VPN will be available in Q1, 2015; that means Beta and GA is likely to happen between Jan- Mar.

Answer (score 0):

the updates i have been receiving is the beta launch is likely around end Feb 2015.

Comment: Great to know. I ended up temporarily using strongswan in GCE because I was in a hurry to migrate our servers. But I'll start testing with google VPN in beta as soon as it's available. Thanks!